# Loading STL objects in Swift 2 (Metal)

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, metal, stl-format

I'm trying to create a 3D model viewer, i've gone through a few tutorials for OpenGL and Metal to create 3D models and do some basic rotations with the pan gesture etc. This example from [www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/93997/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-part-3-adding-texture), a [Sample Project Git(error free)](https://github.com/amornn/MetalTut), the one on the web(original code) has some errors with Xcode 7.1.1. I want to load STL files to display on the device instead of the Cube. I've searched a lot, but can't find tutorials for loading STL files to project 3d object onto the view (Metal / Swift).

Any help would be great. I'm using swift 2 with xCode 7.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 9 (and OS X 10.11 and tvOS), the [Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ModelIO/Reference/ModelIO_Framework/index.html) framework provides help for loading 3D assets from file formats like (and including) STL. By using Model I/O together with [GLKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKit_Collection/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010915) or [MetalKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MetalKit/Reference/MTKFrameworkReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015356), you can load those assets right into OpenGL or Metal buffers for rendering.

Apple has a sample code project called [MetalKitEssentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/MetalKitEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows a bunch of this stuff in action — it's ObjC, but all the relevant API calls are the same in Swift so it's pretty easy to translate, especially if you already have some working Swift Metal code to reference.

Comment: Thnx, will check it out Monday.

Comment: Jeff Biggus gave a talk at 360iDev 2015, and here's his MetalKitEssentials code converted to Swift. https://github.com/hyperjeff/360iDev2015